# GameObject Rotation does not happen on Client Side

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

Flip a 2d GameObject and place it on exact the same position works well on both sides.
Rotating 2d GameObject works well on both sides

However, if i flip the GameObject, by executing Cmd_DoTheSpawn, the rotation is not reflected on the "other" client.

I would need help to get this work.

Here is the code I use:

```
[Command]
void Cmd_DoTheSpawn(GameObject myGameObject) {

    // Check if front or back?
    char lastChar = myGameObject.tag[myGameObject.tag.Length - 1];

    if (lastChar == 'B') {
        convertedObjectTag = unet_Back2Front [myGameObject.tag];
    } else {
        convertedObjectTag = unet_Front2Back [myGameObject.tag];
    }

    GameObject my1 = Resources.Load (convertedObjectTag) as GameObject;

    float z = myGameObject.transform.localEulerAngles.z;

    //var go = (GameObject)Instantiate (my1, myGameObject.transform.position, myGameObject.transform.localRotation);
    var go = (GameObject)Instantiate(my1, myGameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, z));
    go.name = go.name.Remove(go.name.Length - 7); // Remove the '(Clone)' in name

    NetworkServer.SpawnWithClientAuthority(go, base.connectionToClient);

    print ("myGameObject: " + myGameObject.transform.position);

    if (myGameObject == null)
        print ("myGameObject NULL" + myGameObject.transform.position);

    Rpc_DoTheRot (go, myGameObject);

    myNetID = myGameObject.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity> ();
    Cmd_DestroyGameObject (myNetID.netId);
}
```

Thanks to @LumbusterTick i did get it to work, meaning the rotation is ok. However, i did get another problem that i do not fully understand.

I added the following code:

```
[ClientRpc]
public void Rpc_DoTheRot(GameObject newGO, GameObject oldGO) {
    print ("Rpc_DoTheRot");

    if (newGO == null)
        print ("newGO NULL");
    if (oldGO == null)
        print ("oldGO NULL");

    newGO.transform.rotation = oldGO.transform.rotation;
}
```

...which i call after spawn but prior to destroy, see updated code above.

It does place the flipped prefab in correct rotation but i do get the following messages:

> oldGO NULL

as well as:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I know perfectly well what that means but not why it happen as all values of the myGameObject is nulled when i send them. ...and i do it prior to destroy.

I do not understand why it is null but still effect the rotation on the new object.

Comment: Are you using a network transform ?

Comment: Im using unet also and there can be many possibilities why its not working , if the object is spawning on client side , and not flipping(rotating) then the values are not syncing.

Comment: @LumbusterTick I use scripts for network transform. That is not the problem as it works when i rotate in the game but when i replace the prefab, on the same position, with spawn the prefab always ends up with zero rotation. I do realize that the values are not syncing but do not understand as i am specifying the current rotation from the actual prefab that i take the pos from as well.

Comment: ok lets try different things , and this really helped me once , from you command function after you network spawn call a clientrpc function and pass instantiated gameobject to it and change its rotation there and tell me if that worked ,if it wont this means something is wrong here and try to resourceload inside the instantiate function see if that helps

Comment: @LumbusterTick It works :-) However, i do get errors. See update in original post. I managed the error with "try & catch" but do not understand why i get the error, but it works. Also, please write a formal answer so i can mark it complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you command function after you network spawn call a clientrpc function and pass instantiated gameobject to it and change its rotation there.